# Fill up a vector with input from a user

Tags: c++, vector

I am learning c++ and i have a problem with filling a vector with the input from the user. wWenever i try to run my code, a window pops-up with 'vector subscript out of range'  written in it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


using namespace std;

 
int main()
{
    
    int s(0), values(0);
    vector <int> grades;
    cout << "Enter the number of grades you want to enter: \n";
    cin >> s;

    cout << "Enter the values:";
    for (int i(0); i < s; i++)
    {
        cin >> values;
        grades.push_back(values);

    }
    int grades_size(grades.size());
    

    int average(0);
    for (int m(0); m <= grades_size; m++)
    {
        average += grades[m];
    }
    
    average /= grades_size;
    cout << "Your average is" << average;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a close look at `for (int m(0); m <= grades_size; m++)`. How often will this loop - for example - when `grades_size == 1`? What's the last index it will access?

Comment: The valid indices are `0, ..., grades.size() - 1`; `grades.size()` is not a valid index, but in your last iteration you use this value as index. Also you may want to consider using a floating point division and adding a space before printing the average.

Comment: Please learn to format helpfully https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help And if the sytem tells you that you should add more non-code, do so by explaining more, reporting more, showing more, asking more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You can read things from input using streams.

The following example shows how to use the succinct syntax of ranges to do that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/istream.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
int main()
{
    auto vec = ranges::istream<int>(std::cin) | ranges::to_vector;

    for (auto elem : vec) {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
}
```